# Regular Expression (PYTHON)

Tags: python, regex

I have an HTML form where I ask the user to enter his/her email address. I can only proceed/ Submit the form if the email is of the form:  first.last@example.com

The "first" and "last" can be anything, but it has to have the "." in the middle and it has to end with "@example.com".
Could anybody tell me the regular expression I can use for that?

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: Well, nothing so far. I'm new to python and the regex tutorials had way too much information to take in at once.

Comment: @user1987508.. Then learn it step by step. Of course you can't grab everything on one go. You need to learn some concept, apply it on multiple problems in multiple way. This is how you learn. We don't solve someone's problem here, unless he has tried something by himself. So, please first come up with some solution.

Comment: This is rather curious from a user experience angle. Why would you reject people who enter a valid email address that just happens to not contain a period? Also, [obligatory link to a regex that parses most email addresses](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) (spoiler: it's a hundred lines long)

Comment: @Kevin since OP is mandating a specific domain, no doubt he/she knows that the company only assigns emails in the format first.last.

Comment: You might be interested in [this eclipse plugin for regex testing](http://myregexp.com/eclipsePlugin.html)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
r'^([^@.]+)\.([^@.]+)@example\.com$'
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `$` matches the end.
- By writing `^...$`, you make sure the string looks *exactly* like your regex. Things like `foo.bar@example.comasdfg` won't match.
- `[^@.]+` matches sequences of consecutive characters that aren't `@` or `.`.

A non-regex solution would be something like this:

```
def validate_email(email):
    if not email.endswith('@example.com'):
        return False

    chunks = email.split('.')

    return len(chunks) == 3 and all(chunks)
```

Comment: Probably want to disallow `@` in the groups, otherwise eg 'foo.bar@blah@example.com' matches.

Comment: I like that you try to present both regex and non-regex approaches.  Unfortunately, avoiding regex here does make things a lot more verbose.  For example, if you only split on '.' and are satisfied with any three nonempty chunks, then you accept things like 'foo.@example.com' or '@.@example.com'.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Technically `@` is a valid character for the local part of an email (eg: `"abc@def"@example.com` is a valid email according to RFC 2821)

Comment: @JohnY: You could probably simplify the last line to just `return len(chunks) == 3 and all(chunks)`. I like the non-regex solution, personally.

Comment: I usually prefer non-regex myself, but what you've presented is too permissive (if I'm understanding the OP).  It's certainly more permissive than your regex.

Comment: @JohnY: The only things that squeeze through are other `@` signs. You could add in `email.count('@') == 1` and fix that. It's just another way of doing it.

Comment: See my earlier example: You also let through 'foo.@example.com'. If you want to present a non-regex alternative, I think you should make it do the same thing as the regex, or at least explicitly state how it differs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression, you could use:

```
def email_validator(email):
    if not email.endswith('@example.com'):
        return False

    if not email[:-12].count('.') == 1:
        return False
    return True
```

Edit: Fixed with suggestions from @John Y, @manu-fatto

Comment: like that you admin many '.' in the prefix

Comment: The best way to check whether the end of a string matches some exact, literal characters is not to use a slice, but the `endswith` string method.  Your first `if` statement would simply be `if not email.endswith('@example.com'):`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `^(.+?)\.(.+?)@example\.com$` .  The `.+?` part means there has to be something before and after the `.` in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `r'^(\w*?)\.(\w*?)@example\.com$'`. This is identical to Blender's answer, except  that it limits the contents of "first" and "last" to "word" characters, which include upper and lower case letters, digits, and the underscore (`_`). If you'd like to allow more characters, such as `-`, you can do so by replacing the `@` in the alternate version below:

`r'^([\w@]*?)\.([\w@]*?)@example\.com$'`

For instance, if you want to allow `-` and `&`, it would be:

`r'^([\w&\-]*?)\.([\w&\-]*?)@example\.com$'`

(The backslash in front of the `-` is because `-` has a special meaning inside of character classes.)